# gridview update always does select rows first?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview populated form a local sql db via an sqldatasource.

The select command of the sqldatasource is: `SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [CERecord] ORDER BY [Priority]"`

In my code behind I have a radio button list which displays either all records, active records, completed records:

```
protected void rblShowRecords_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (rblShowRecords.SelectedValue)
        {
            case "Show Active/Completed":
                CEDatabaseSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [CERecord] ORDER BY [Priority]";
                break;
            case "Show Active":
                CEDatabaseSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [CERecord] WHERE [Completed]='false' ORDER BY [Priority]";
                break;
            case "Show Completed":
                CEDatabaseSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [CERecord] WHERE [Completed]='true' ORDER BY [Priority]";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        CEDatabaseSource.DataBind();
        gvRecordList.DataBind();
    }
```

I am having a strange issue when if I try to update a row when in either active only or completed only mode, it seems to just start showing all rows even though I set the new command in the method above.

When you click update on a row in gridview, does it always run the default select command: `SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [CERecord] ORDER BY [Priority]"` ?

Answer (score 0):

When you click the Update button on the row, it is changing the selected index, so it will run your selectedIndexChanged event.

The best way I can think of to not fire off this SQL every time you click the grid is to move your code into a different method that doesn't fire on every click.

It's also worth noting that you are using inline SQL - this is a BIG security flaw.  While it's not so bad for SELECT statements, it's a bad habit to get into.  Use some paramaterized stored procedures or a Data Access Layer to get your data instead, and remember to validate your inputs.

Comment: It seems that everytime I click the Update link, it does a postback and run the original selectcommand of the sqldatasource, even though has already been updated.